# Text box in android

Tags: android, android-studio, textbox

I wonder where can I get the `text box`(as shown in diagram below) at the left panel of `android studio`? As I can see, there only has `textFields` which has a line below the text but not text box.

[image]

Comment: Does android studio provide this kind of text box? Because I can't find it

Comment: I believe it's an edittext where you are typing

Comment: Where can I get such text box instead of a line under the typing text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `EditText`. I believe in Android Studio it is the TextField which has a line below. Just using a different theme. To get the TextBox look you need to use one of the old themes like `@android:style/Theme.Light for your application.

Comment: put @android:style/Theme in my activity.xml?

Comment: @Hoo put it in **AndroidManifest.xml** where you set your theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such object "TextBox" in Android.

What you are seeing is the name of the app in the app's title bar.

It's supplied by the system.

Answer (score 0):

as others had suggested it's a system-default theme from an older API, however it isn't used much and its design is a bit out-dated. i'd highly suggest wrapping a EditText in a  drawable, since it'd give you control of the design, and make it more visually stimulating =) the plus side is it's very simply to create a shape drawable in xml!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the EditText to create such textbox in android studio, example is displayed below

```
<EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="type your name here"
          android:id="@+id/edit_text"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the text box in the Text section of the Palette. Click on the "Plain Text" label, and drag it to your designer.

[image]

If you click on the button below, you will see the xml code. The textbox is called EditText.

[image]