# How to create a square text box in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I have to create an `activity` which should contain a square text box in which user can write notes and save by clicking a button.

The sample activity is attached here:

[image]

I've done enough research, the most I found to create custom `TextView` in that I can give input texts in a single line, but I need to create like I can go for a next line while giving input itself.

Can any body help me out how to perform this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138862/text-box-in-android this is a related question, if not the same

Comment: I request you to check the attached sample pic.

Comment: Sorry, I can't, my company has those links forbidden

Comment: Actually I can't post picture without having at least 10 reputation, So

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 <EditText
  android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="text6 demo" />
```

**create backgound like this in your drawble folder**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! after increasing the height it gives desired square text box. Can you give any solution to place the cursor at the top-left of field instead of center_left as I've attached the sample pic.

Comment: In case anyone is reading this and facing the same cursor placement problem, add `android:gravity="top|left"` to have the cursor move to the top left.